# Do Brock PaverBase mats make pavers hotter?

Tags: pavers

Would Brock PaverBase mats make pavers hotter because they do not allow the pavers to dissipate the heat to the sand below them? I'm wondering if these mats would be bad to use on a pool deck?

http://www.brockpaverbase.com/paver-base-installation/

Comment: Select light colored pavers if you are worried about the heat of the pool deck. I don't know what the R-value would be of this polypropylene but it can't be much. The main concern is direct sunlight heating the tops of the pavers. The darker the color the hotter they will get in the sun. That is one reason why concrete is preferable to asphalt for a pool deck. Other than that you could add strategically placed shade to keep things cooler.

Comment: A: 20mm (Brock) PaverBase provides the same thermal insulation properties of 9″ stone. It has the same “R” value as EPS so it is essentially similar to the Polystyrene used to insulate houses, only much more durable to withstand a paver application.